# jQuery Ajax results in 0-byte post in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a web application that uses jQuery AJAX extensively. I am having an issue where IE 11 does not submit the data to the server (0-byte post).

I have made this simple jsfiddle that reproduces the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/CZGEH/6/

```
$("#ajax").click(function () {
    var d = {
        a: 1
    };
    alert("before: " + d.a);
    var json = JSON.stringify(d);  
    $.post("/echo/json/", { json: json}, 
           function (r) {
               alert("after: " + r.a);
           }
          );
});
```

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, showing the value before and after, but in IE11, the request body is empty, and of course nothing is returned from the echo because nothing was sent. I've verified that the POST is empty using the network panel of the IE F12 Developer tools.

UPDATE: Fiddle capture

```
Key Value
Request POST /echo/json/ HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://jsfiddle.net/CZGEH/6/show/
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host    jsfiddle.net
Content-Length  0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  __utma=210580238.1033480112.1361288166.1398353560.1398356067.4;             __utmz=210580238.1398353560.3.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csrftoken=bknsZsUQNq1vkwRg0jUjYUJajySxummK
```

UPDATE:
      It was the "Google Gears Helper" add on being enabled that was breaking the script. The script is not using the pluggin, and it was actually very simple. I still dont know why is it breaking, but disabling the add on removes the problem. Marking as answer, thanks Erick!!

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you only test this in jsfiddle? Does it work with IE 11 if you test it in jsfiddle with that url : [http://fiddle.jshell.net/CZGEH/6/show/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CZGEH/6/show/) ?

Comment: It does not work on IE11, even outside jsfiddle, tried the link with the /show too. Also, this is very simple example to replicate the problem, I have several real life pages where it has the same problem.

Comment: Is the first `alert` shown? Does IE11 show some error message in the console? A common problem (not sure if also with IE 11) is that if IE is not in Standart Mode but in a Compatibly mode (either triggered by `doctype` or directly by the user), then it also uses the old JS engine which does not have `JSON`. If the first `alert` is shown, then you could check if `window.JSON` is `undefined`, if so then IE is in Compatibility mode for some reason.

Comment: Both the alerts show, the second with 'undefined'. No errors on the console. JSON is defined. alert(json) before making the call produces {"a":1}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing this with the current version of IE11 with all updates, the message box is shown twice and the HTTP form is POST'd to the server. As seen in Fiddler:

```
  POST http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/ HTTP/1.1
  Accept: */*
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/CZGEH/6/show/
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  Host: fiddle.jshell.net
  Content-Length: 22
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Pragma: no-cache

  json=%7B%22a%22%3A1%7D
```

Please verify that you can reproduce this in **No Add-ons mode** in the browser, and verify that you do not have any 3rd party "Download Manager" plugins or other extensions (like Google Gears) that thunk IE's network stack installed.

Extensions using undocumented means to alter IE's network stack are known to have bugs which cause 0-byte POSTs.

Comment: Still showing the problem, using latest IE 11.0.9600.17041 Update version 11.0.7: post request shows browser: Key Value
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko.... ANd request body length:0, empty body

Comment: The capture is from the network panel on the IE11 debugging tools. I dont know what you refer to by fiddle capture. I did not have any special add on installed, but just to humor you I went and disabled all the add-ons using the Group Policy Editor, something I assume a lot user wont have permission to do..., but anyway. And that WORKED, disabling the add ons makes the script work, I am going to enable the add ons one be one and see which one makes it break, but thanks a lot for your help. Marking as answer, would you please update your answer to say to disable the addons? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It was actually the "Google Gears Helper" add-on. I tried disabling it, and the script works. When I enable it again the script fails again... That script is not using Gears, at all, why is that failing??

Comment: The (deprecated) Google Gears plugin uses undocumented "thunks" to rewrite functions inside Internet Explorer's network stack. It wasn't updated to do so correctly for IE11 and as a consequence this problem arises.